# Stop Thunderbird changing color of Google Calendar events

Tags: thunderbird, google-calendar

I have configured Thunderbird to sync with my Google Calendar. The two-way sync works perfectly, but every time I sync Thunderbird with my Google Calendar, it changes the color of all past events to grey (regardless of what color I had originally set for the event). I am using [Lightning and Provider for Google Calendar](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/using-lightning-google-calendar) to sync.

Is there a way to prevent this from happening? Thanks!

Comment: What method are you using to sync?

Comment: @fixer1234, I'm using Lightning. I've changed the question to clarify. Thanks.